# java pattern to clean quotes around other chars from mapper generated string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, replaceall

i need replace json mapper generated string sequences as fallow:

```
:"{ -> :{   
}"} -> }}
```

how would look pattern for that ?

**update: full string example**

```
{"method":"createInvoice","params":"{"btcDue":null,"btcPaid":null,
                        "btcPrice":null,"currency":"PLN","currentTime":null,
                        "exceptionStatus":null,"expirationTime":null,
                        "guid":"99250130","id":null,"invoiceTime":null,
                        "paymentUrls":null,"price":1.23,"rate":null,
                        "status":null,"transactions":null,"url":null
}"}
```

but assume we will have more instances to replace like 2 :)

**to clarify: android String methods**

```
 public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    String replacementStr = replacement.toString();
    String targetStr = target.toString();
    // Special case when target == "". 
    // .. cut 
    // This is the "regular" case.
    int lastMatch = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    for (;;) {
        int currentMatch = indexOf(this, targetStr, lastMatch);
        if (currentMatch == -1) {
            break;
        }
        if (sb == null) {
            sb = new StringBuilder(count);
        }
        sb.append(this, lastMatch, currentMatch);
        sb.append(replacementStr);
        lastMatch = currentMatch + targetStr.count;
    }

    if (sb != null) {
        sb.append(this, lastMatch, count);
        return sb.toString();
    } else {
        return this;
    }
 }

 public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement);
}
```

Comment: A simple `.replace("\"", "");` wouldn't work?

Comment: @CaioOliveira - no as  string contains double quotes which i need to preserve

Answer (score 1):

Nothing difficult about it:

```
String result = "{\"method\":\"createInvoice\",\"params\":\"{\"btcDue\":null,\"btcPaid\":null,\"btcPrice\":null,\"currency\":\"PLN\",\"currentTime\":null,\"exceptionStatus\":null,\"expirationTime\":null,\"guid\":\"99250130\",\"id\":null,\"invoiceTime\":null,\"paymentUrls\":null,\"price\":1.23,\"rate\":null,\"status\":null,\"transactions\":null,\"url\":null}\"}"
    .replace(":\"{", ":{")
    .replace("}\"}", "}}");
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: i thought this way but if i need replace all instances ?  i need to loop...

Comment: Java is weird, `replaceAll(pattern, replacement)` replaces all instances using regex, while `replace(pattern, replacement)` replaces all instances without regex ...

Comment: You can use `replaceAll`, too, if you want: `src.replaceAll("\\:\"\\{", ":{").replaceAll("\\}\"\\}", "}}")`

Comment: replaceAll  is equal -> Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement); and   public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) has no pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can match all quotes surrounded by `:`+`{` and `}`+`}` using the [lookahead/lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) construct:

```
(?<=})"(?=})|(?<=:)"(?={)
```

Pass this to `replaceAll` to remove the quotes ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ISbtg5/1)).

Comment: this replace all " in my string - probably  as its art/android  java regex implementation i get methodcreateInvoice,paramsbtcDuenull,btcPaidnull,btcPricenull,currencyPLN,currentTimenull,exRatesnull,exceptionStatusnull,expirationTimenull,guid99250130,idnull,invoiceTimenull,paymentUrlsnull,price1.23,ratenull,statusnull,transactionsnull,urlnull

Comment: @ceph3us That os odd. You added a backslash `'\'` in front of `"` in the regex string to make it a valid string literal, right?

Comment: compiled pattern Pattern.compile("[()?<=})\"(?=})|(?<=:)\"(?={]").pattern()

Answer (score 0):

**Search by**

```
\"
```

**Then replace it to ""**

**Original Text**

```
:"{   
}"}
```

**Result**

```
:{
}}
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "\\\"";
final String string = ":\"{ -> :{   \n"
     + "}\"} -> }} ";
final String subst = "";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```